# How to execute protoc on a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, protoc

Currently I have installed protobuf in a jupyter notebook with the following command:

```
%pip install protobuf
```

I can confirm the package is installed.
I then attempt to check the version of it like so, to ensure it's installed:

```
!protoc --version
```

I get the error:

```
/bin/bash: protoc: command not found
```

When I run `%pip install protobuf` again it says the package is installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (3.19.6)
```

Any idea what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed the protoc compiler which is a separate and is needed to compile .proto file into language-specific source files.

```
!sudo apt-get install -y protobuf-compiler
```